# Cauchy Schwarz inequality on scalar terms

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, normed-spaces

The following equations are derived from Quantum information theory, which requires the use of Cauchy Schwarz inequality for a proof.

I am quite puzzled by the second term in the summation, which consists of a sum over the product of a square norm and an absolute value i.e. the product of two scalars!,  my question is : isn't cauchy schwarz inequality strictly applied to vectors only?

I found the closest thing to the one i had is the Rn dimension from Wiki, but xi, yi there are component of a vector in which my case isn't.

[image]

[image]

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1681300

Comment: Do you mean it is true that n = 1 i.e. scalar? still works?

Comment: If $n = 1 $ then all it says is $(xy)^2 \le x^2y^2$ and since they are the same this is clearly true.